# ¿Cómo Almacenar Multiple Docu en un input Type POST dentro de un array dinamico de POST?

Tags: javascript, php, phpmyadmin

Buen día, mostraré mi código y espero ser los más detallado posible.
1.- Tengo una etiqueta form html, en dónde agrupo un div con post.
código:

tengo este button type button con un click.

```
<button type="button" onclick="addfiles();" class="btn btn-outline-info m-1 px-5 radius-30">Añadir Conceptos</button>
```

en dónde por medio de un javascript realizo la función append

```
function addfiles() {
    var countfile = parseFloat($("#countfile").val()) + 1;
    $("#countfile").val(countfile);

var id = 'div_' + countfile;

$("#rowfilesmultiple").append('<div class="row" id="' + id + '"><div class="col-md-5"><label for="beneficiario" class="form-label">Beneficiario</label><input type="text" class="form-control" name="beneficiario[]" id="beneficiario" onkeyup="javascript:this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();"></div><div class="col-md-5"><label for="concepagos" class="form-label">Concepto del Pago</label><input type="text" class="form-control" name="concepagos[]" id="concepagos" onkeyup="javascript:this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();"></div><div class="col-md-2"><label for="tipoPago" class="form-label">Tipo de Pago</label><input type="text" class="form-control" name="tipoPago[]" id="tipoPago" value="TRS" onkeyup="javascript:this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();"></div><div class="col-md-1"><label for="moneda" class="form-label">Moneda</label><input type="text" class="form-control" name="moneda[]" id="moneda" value="MXN" onkeyup="javascript:this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();"></div><div class="col-md-2"><label for="total" class="form-label">Total</label><input type="number" min="0" step="0.00" class="form-control" name="total[]" id="total"></div><div class="col-md-4"><label for="imgFiles" class="form-label">Archivos</label><input type="file" class="form-control" id="formFileMultiple"  name="imgFiles[]" accept="image/png,image/jpeg,image/jpg,application/pdf,.doc,.docx" multiple></div><div class="col-md-4" style="margin-top:25px;"><button type="button" onclick="daletefiles(this.id);" id="' + id + '" class="btn btn-outline-danger m-1 px-5 radius-30">Quitar</button></div><br><br><hr></div>');
```

el cual pues me agrupa a este form:

```
<form class="row g-3" id="formaddexpdigifiles" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="hidden" name="countfile" id="countfile" value="0">
      <input type="hidden" name="datefiles" id="datefiles">
      <div id="rowfilesmultiple"></div>
</form>
```

y el resultado es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

al momento de guardar lo realizo de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php
    require('connect.php');
    session_start();

    $nameuser = $_SESSION['datos']['nombre'];
    $idUser = $_SESSION['datos']['id'];

    date_default_timezone_set('America/Mexico_City');
    $fecha = date("Y-m-d");
    $hora = date('H:i:s');
    $year = date('Y');

    $d = explode("|", $_POST['datefiles']);
    $idexp = $d[0];
    $expen = $d[1];

    $countarre =  count($_POST['beneficiario']);

    $estatus = 1;
    $beneficiario = $_POST['beneficiario'];
    $concepagos = $_POST['concepagos'];
    $tipoPago = $_POST['tipoPago'];
    $moneda = $_POST['moneda'];
    $total = $_POST['total'];

    $array_id = array();

    for ($i=0; $i < $countarre; $i++) { 

        //$sql = "INSERT INTO comprobante_exp VALUES (NULl,"."'".$idexp."', '".$beneficiario[$i]."','".$concepagos[$i]."','".$tipoPago[$i]."','".$moneda[$i]."','".$total[$i]."','".$nameuser."','".$fecha."','".$hora."','".$estatus."')";

        $sql = "INSERT INTO comprobante_exp VALUES (NULL,'$idexp','$beneficiario[$i]','$concepagos[$i]','$tipoPago[$i]','$moneda[$i]','$total[$i]','$nameuser','$fecha','$hora','$estatus')";

        $insertexped = $con->query($sql);

        $selectMaxidexpdoc = $con->query("SELECT @@identity AS idexpdoc FROM comprobante_exp");
        $rowMaxidexpodc = $selectMaxidexpdoc->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $idexpendoc = $rowMaxidexpodc['idexpdoc'];

array_push($array_id,$idexpendoc);
        if($insertexped){

            $insertOperacion = $con->query("INSERT INTO operaciones VALUES(NULL,'SE CARGO LOS COMPROBANTES DEL EXPEDIENTE $expen','$fecha','$hora','$nameuser','$idUser','EXPEDIENTE','1')");

        }
    }

    for ($j=0; $j < count($array_id); $j++) {
        // $carpeta_folio = '../expdiente/'.$year.'/'.$expen.'/'.$beneficiario[$i];
        $carpeta_folio = '../expdiente/'.$year.'/'.$expen.'/Comprobantes';
        $exis_exp = '../expdiente/'.$year.'/'.$expen;

        foreach ($_FILES["imgFiles"]["name"] as $key => $value) {

            $imgFiles = $_FILES["imgFiles"]["name"][$key];
            
            if (!file_exists($exis_exp)) {

                mkdir($exis_exp, 0777, true);

                if (!file_exists($carpeta_folio)) {

                    mkdir($carpeta_folio, 0777, true);
                    $destino = $carpeta_folio.'/'.$_FILES["imgFiles"]["name"][$key];
                    $upload = @move_uploaded_file($_FILES["imgFiles"]["tmp_name"][$key],$destino);

                }else{

                    $destino = $carpeta_folio.'/'.$_FILES["imgFiles"]["name"][$key];
                    $upload = @move_uploaded_file($_FILES["imgFiles"]["tmp_name"][$key],$destino);
                }

            }else{

                if (!file_exists($carpeta_folio)) {

                    mkdir($carpeta_folio, 0777, true);
                    $destino = $carpeta_folio.'/'.$_FILES["imgFiles"]["name"][$key];
                    $upload = @move_uploaded_file($_FILES["imgFiles"]["tmp_name"][$key],$destino);

                }else{

                    $destino = $carpeta_folio.'/'.$_FILES["imgFiles"]["name"][$key];
                    $upload = @move_uploaded_file($_FILES["imgFiles"]["tmp_name"][$key],$destino);

                }

            }

            $insert_archi = $con->query("INSERT INTO files_compro_exp VALUES(NULL,'$array_id[$j]','$imgFiles','$fecha','$hora','$nameuser',1)");
        }
    }

    print json_encode(array('resp' => 1, 'ids' => $array_id));
```

dónde cuento el array del post beneficiario y por ende los demás post tendrán la misma cantidad, mi duda es cuanto intento guardar las imagenes en un file multuple me los repite

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

se supone que añadir 2 doc por cada imput pero me guardó 4 veces.

espero a ver explicado mi duda y espero que me puedan apoyar